# Oscar Django many categories slow down the site

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-oscar

I've created a site ( Clothing Shop )  which has 426 categories . The site is really slow due to having many categories . ( Even when creating a child category it is saved in Category at the database as seen from shell (oscar category creation)) . I've tried many methods to optimize the queries that are made when a page is loading but still too slow . I've followed the django doc for optimized categories (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/optimization/) . I've also tried to cache some queries . Moreover the fact that I think the slowness comes from categories is because I've seen that the category queries take the most time through django toolbar .Any help would be great ! . ( Also sorry if my question is not well written I am kinda new around here )

Comment: Have you considered pagination?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer ! I 've tried pagination ( but now I use see more feature ) and still no difference .